# create stacked bar chart with multiple dimensions

Tags: tableau-api

Totaly noob to Tableau, using desktop version 10.0, no access to Tableau Public thanks to work restrictions.

I'm plotting school data by school district. Data dimensions are District, Level (Primary v. Secondary), and Ownership (Pubic v. Private). I want to know how I can make a stacked bar chart that incorporates multiple dimensions (not multiple measures).

For example, I want a bar that shows number of schools in a district, with color breakdown to indicate Public Primary, Public Secondary, Private Primary, Private Secondary.

Currently I have Rows: District; Columns: Number of Schools; Color (under marks): Level. This works fine, but I'm unable to add school ownership as another way to disaggregate.

Do I need to go back into R to make another column that joins Level and Ownership in order for Tableau to be able to figure this out?

Comment: Try dragging Ownership to Rows also, either before or after District. Or put Ownership on Columns. Or Pages. Or hold down the shift key, and add to Color. Play around and have fun and eventually it will start to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Clare, you will need to create a calculated field.  Call it "Level + Ownership" and add the calc:

```
[Level]+":"+[Ownership]
```

Place the calc on the color card...should be good to go.